# Flutter: type _file is not a subtype of type widget

Tags: image, flutter, file, widget

i am getting type _file is not a subtype of type widget error and this is my code.
i am trying to move my cropped image that i cropped in cropImage to editImage widget.

```
  _getFromGallery() async {
XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery,
  maxWidth: 1800,
  maxHeight: 1800,
);
_cropImage(pickedFile!.path);
```

}

```
_cropImage(pickedFile) async {
File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: pickedFile,
  maxWidth: 1080,
  maxHeight: 1080,
);
if (croppedImage != null) {
  image = croppedImage;
  Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => editImage(croppedImage)));
}
```

}

```
  Widget editImage(croppedImage) {
final Future<String> _croppedImage = Future<String>.delayed(
  const Duration(seconds: 2),
  () => 'Data Loaded',
);
return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _croppedImage,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {}
      return Center(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Edit Image'),
          ),
          body: Container(child: image = croppedImage),
        ),
      );
    });
```

}
}

can i get the right code example? im stuck in this for weeks. please help.

Answer (score 2):

flutter root tree can show only classes who inherited from the widget class. change your code to this :

```
   Widget editImage(croppedImage) {
final Future<String> _croppedImage = Future<String>.delayed(
  const Duration(seconds: 2),
  () => 'Data Loaded',
);
return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _croppedImage,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {}
      return Center(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Edit Image'),
          ),
          body:croppedImage !=null? Container(child: Image.file(croppedImage!)):null,
        ),
      );
    });
} }
```

Comment: walla gever gever!